# Add Insecure Registry to Docker in ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am trying to add private registry in docker on ubuntu machine, using nexus as repository

below is the screenshot of nexus configurations

[image]

in docker host i have added `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=xx.xx.xx.xx:8083"` to `/etc/default/docker`

after these changes i did docker restart using below commands

```
 systemctl daemon-reload
 systemctl restart docker
```

now when i execute `docker info` its not showing up my private registry

[image]

is anything missing in my configurations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding insecure registry entry in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

file content

```
{ "insecure-registries":["registry.example.com"] }
```

restart the docker deamon

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: If it does not work then check ´sudo docker info´. Check in the end if your repository is added to ´Insecure Registries:´. This does not work if the docker is installed using snap or some other way.